# Exception: ERROR: The 'make' utility is missing from PATH

Tags: pip, discord, pynacl

I am having an error when trying to install a package from pip called DiscordUtils
Exception: ERROR: The 'make' utility is missing from PATH
and
ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyNaCl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Comment: You likely don't have the `make` utility installed. What operating system are you running?

Comment: its windows 10 64bit

Comment: Any help i can get?

Comment: Is [this](https://pypi.org/project/DiscordUtils/) the pip package you are referring to? Are you sure you are running `pip install` directly on Windows? I don't expect that it would expect `make` to be installed if you are installing on Windows. Can you also please post the full output of `pip install`?

Comment: Yes that is the package I'm referring

Comment: I'm running pip install on my command prompt